# Get WP posts based on multiple meta key/value pairs using IN

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm having some trouble formatting my query to fetch a list of posts from the database based on the value of two meta values. I'm using WordPress 4.9.4 and I need to use `$wpdb->get_results()` and **not** a normal `get_posts()` function call with arguments.

Here is what I have so far, but if I try and include the `IN` part in the MySQL query, it doesn't return anything but it should return at least one post.

```php
global $wpdb;

$posts = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        'SELECT ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts.*, ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta.* FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts, ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta WHERE ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts.post_type = %s AND ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta.post_id = ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts.ID AND (' . $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta.meta_key = %s AND ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta.meta_value = %s) AND (' . $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta.meta_key = %s AND ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta.meta_value IN (%s)) ORDER BY ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts.post_title ASC LIMIT %d OFFSET %d',
        'book',
        'book_genre',
        $genre,
        'category',
        '239, 440',
        $limit,
        $offset
    )
);
```

The above query should get all posts where:

- the post has a `post_type` of `book` in `wp_posts`
- has a meta_key of `book_genre` and meta_value of `fiction` in `wp_postmeta`
- has a meta_key of `category` and meta_value of `239, 440` in `wp_postmeta`
- limit results to `xyz`
- offset results of `xyz`

However, the above query returns a value of `null` if I `var_dump( $posts );` onto the page, so I imagine that the in part is causing some sort of conflict with the first meta key/value rule, perhaps?

If I remove the `IN` part of the query it gets everything as expected minus the filtering of the categories of course that I'd like. The category ids are an array of ids that are converted into a comma-separated string using PHP's `implode()`.

For example:

- Post `1` has a post_type of `book`, has a meta key/value pair of `book_genre` and `fiction` and has a meta key/value pair of 'category' and `440` so ***should*** be included using the above query.
- Post `2` has a post_type of `book`, has a meta key/value pair of `book_genre` and `fiction` and has a meta key/value pair of 'category' and `323` so ***should not*** be included using the above query.

Comment: It's not clearer and no one should have to decipher this.  If you need help with your _query_, then just give us a raw MySQL query, and sample input/output data.  If your query already works, and you need PHP help, then tell us this.

Comment: When I say query, I mean `$wpdb` query which is turned into a MySQL query through the WordPress query method. I understand it's a tricky question to ask and answer, but it's one I've not found anything like before, either it's unique or I might have phrased it differently. The gist is how do I write it in a way that selects posts based on two meta key/value pairs. It seems it's written incorrectly to support two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the `post_meta` table twice. Here's some database theory.

When you join tables, in theory a temporary table contains all of the items from the first table combined with all of the items from the second table is created and filtered. So if, for example, you have just 1 meta item per post, and you have 3 posts then you have

```
+-------+----------+
|post_id|post_title|
+-------+----------+
|   1   | 'Post 1' |
|   2   | 'Post 2' |
|   3   | 'Post 3' |
+-------+----------+
```

and

```
+-------+----------+----------+------------+
|meta_id| post_id  | meta_key | meta_value |
+-------+----------+----------+------------+
|   10  | 1        |  k1      | v1         |
|   11  | 2        |  k1      | v2         |
|   12  | 3        |  k1      | v3         |
+-------+----------+----------+------------+
```

And the "theoretical" temporary joined table is:

```
+---------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|p.post_id|p.post_title|pm.meta_id|pm.post_id|pm.meta_key|pm.meta_value|
+---------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|   1     | 'Post 1'   |   10     | 1        |  k1       | v1          |
|   1     | 'Post 1'   |   11     | 2        |  k1       | v2          |
|   1     | 'Post 1'   |   12     | 3        |  k1       | v3          |
|   2     | 'Post 2'   |   10     | 1        |  k1       | v1          |
|   2     | 'Post 2'   |   11     | 2        |  k1       | v2          |
|   2     | 'Post 2'   |   12     | 3        |  k1       | v3          |
|   3     | 'Post 3'   |   10     | 1        |  k1       | v1          |
|   3     | 'Post 3'   |   11     | 2        |  k1       | v2          |
|   3     | 'Post 3'   |   12     | 3        |  k1       | v3          |
+---------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

You then say: WHERE p.id = pm.post_id

and this filters the temporary table to be:

```
+---------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|p.post_id|p.post_title|pm.meta_id|pm.post_id|pm.meta_key|pm.meta_value|
+---------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|   1     | 'Post 1'   |   10     | 1        |  k1       | v1          |
|   2     | 'Post 2'   |   11     | 2        |  k1       | v2          |
|   3     | 'Post 3'   |   12     | 3        |  k1       | v3          |
+---------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

So you only have one row for each post + meta value. Your query is asking for rows that have both `meta_key = category` and meta_key = book_genre` which don't exist.

So you need a table that joins the `postmeta` table in TWICE.

You can do this by aliasing the table as you join them. Forgive me for simplifying:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, pm1.*, pm2.*
FROM
  wp_posts
  wp_postmeta as pm1
  wp_postmeta as pm2
WHERE pm1.post_id = wp_posts.ID
  AND pm2.post_id = wp_posts.ID
  AND ...etc
```

Here you have two joined copies of the postmeta table aliased to `pm1` and `pm2` (as they can't BOTH be called `wp_postmeta` in the query.

You can then ask for:

```
AND pm1.meta_key = 'category'
AND pm1.meta_value = X
AND pm2.meta_key = 'book_genre'
AND pm2.meta_key IN (123,456)
```

Hopefully you can stitch together the rest from that.

I also think you can do this with WP_Query if you want to go that route.